# Why getting provider error when trying to inject resolved property in controller using ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am unable to inject resolve property of ui-routing in controller.
It is giving

**Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider**

When I'm using controller property in state definition object as following

```
.state('widget', {
    url: '/widgets',
    template: '<h1>{{name}}</h1>',
    controller: function(widget, $scope) {
      $scope.name = widget.name;
    },

    resolve: {
        // standard resolve value promise definition
        widget: function() {
            return {
                name: 'myWidget'
            };
        },
        // resolve promise injects sibling promise
        features: function(widget) {
            return ['featureA', 'featureB'].map(function(feature) { 
                return widget.name+':'+feature;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then it is working fine and I'm able to get the **widget** in controller and able to use in html.

Please see the fiddle for code.

http://jsfiddle.net/sunilmadaan07/ugsx6c1w/8/

Might be I'm making a silly mistake.
Before posting this question I have tried returning with simple object, promise object to the property.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get resolved data in the directive with the code you did. Basically, you are trying to implement component based structure with an older version of angular 1.3.x.

You have two options to achieve this.

- Create route controller then you can access resolve to the controller as local dependency then use that dependency as binding to the directive.
  Here is example - http://plnkr.co/edit/TOPMLUXc7GhXTeYL0IFj?p=preview
- Upgrade angular version to 1.5.x and use `"ui-router-route-to-components": "^0.1.0"`

Here working example of your code - http://jsfiddle.net/ugsx6c1w/25/

Answer (score 0):

In order for the controller to be able to use resolvers, it should be route component (only in UI Router 1.x) or route controller.

`widget` and `features` are local dependencies, they aren't registered in the injector and aren't available anywhere in the application except route controller/component.

As explained [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2793#issuecomment-223764105), resolvers can be passed to nested components in UI Router 0.3.x and injected directly to route components in 1.x.

Comment: I have removed nested resolve from code.
Please have a look 

http://jsfiddle.net/sunilmadaan07/ugsx6c1w/13/

Comment: You can't use `widget` resolver in *nested* show-data component. Switch to UI Router 1.x and use it directly as route component.